# Java Character in String to integer

Tags: java

Everything seem correct until the number is being detected. 
the number 1 should remain as 1.it show be 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0

A = 10 and B = 11 and so on

How do i correct the follow bug

### Code

```
String alpha = "ABCDEFG1234567890";

  for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length(); i++) {
            char c = alpha.charAt(i);
             int w = (int)c;
             System.out.println(w-55);
    }
```

### Output

10
11
12
13
14
15
16
-6
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
0
1
2
-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the method `Character.isDigit()`. Also note that you can cast a `char` to a `int` by using `(int)c`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String alpha = "ABCDEFG1234567890";

    for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length(); i++) {
        char c = alpha.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isDigit((c))) {
            System.out.println(c);
        } else {
            System.out.println((int)c - 55); // Cast to 'int'
        }
    }
}
```

**<sub>Output:</sub>**

```
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String alpha = "ABCDEFG1234567890";

for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length(); i++) {
    char c = alpha.charAt(i);
    int w = (int)c;
    if (w >= 65) {
        System.out.println(w-55);
    } else {
        System.out.println(w-48);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Character.digit(c, 10)` which returns int

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
   {

     String alpha = "ABCDEFG1234567890";

  for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length(); i++) 
  {
            char c = alpha.charAt(i);
   if(c>='1' && c<='9')  
          {
          System.out.print(c); 
          }
   else
         {
             int w = (int)c;
             System.out.print(w-55);
         }
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String alpha = "ABCDEFG1234567890";

      for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length(); i++) {
                char c = alpha.charAt(i);
                int w;
                 if(Character.isDigit(c)){
                     w =Character.digit(c, 10);
                 }else{
                    w = (int)c;
                     w=w-55;
                 }
                 System.out.println(w);
        }
}
```